# emit an object as the value of an observable timer

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to replay a sequence of events stored in a database. So I want to create an Observable stream of Observable timers that ellapse when every event must emit. My problem is that I can't find the appropiate way to have an object be emitted as the value of the timer.

Let me set a simplified (and somewhat contrived) example, but that explains the problem.

Let's begin with a simple array of delay values

```
var delays = [200,100,1000,1200,300,1100];
```

and their corresponding Observable timers

```
var source= Rx.Observable
  .for(delays, t => Rx.Observable.timer(t) );
```

which I can observe

```
source.subscribe( x => console.log(x) );
```

so far so good, obtaining just a list of zeroes at each timer completition.

Then, for the purpouses of this example, I'd like to obtain the events fired at the delay expressed, not in the original order; and I'd like to obtain the original value and index into the array of each timer.

So, I add a simple map in the observable

```
var source= Rx.Observable
  .for(delays, t => Rx.Observable.timer(t) )
  .map((x,i)=>{i,x});
```

And, to check if the timing is acurate, I add a watch in the observer,

```
  var startTime = Date.now();    
  source.subscribe( x => console.log((Date.now()-startTime), x) );
```

> ***this is what I'd like to obtain***
>
> ```
> 142 { i:1, x:100 }
> 204 { i: 0, x: 200 }
> 303 { i: 4, x: 300 }
> 1002 { i: 2, x: 1000 }
> 1101 { i: 5, x: 1100 }
> 1203 { i: 3, x: 1200 }
> ```

I don't get the original index in the array, but the order in which they are being emitted.

> ***this is what I obtain instead***
>
> ```
> 1046 { x: 0, i: 0 }
> 1166 { x: 0, i: 1 }
> 1371 { x: 0, i: 2 }
> 2472 { x: 0, i: 3 }
> 3673 { x: 0, i: 4 }
> 3974 { x: 0, i: 5 }
> ```

What is the most RxJS-esque technique to have an object be emitted as the value of a timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `flatMap` the timer to an observable from an array and `map` the time and index to the timer.

```
const o = Rx.Observable;
const delays = [200,100,1000,1200,300,1100];
const delays$ = o.from(delays)
  .flatMap( (t, i) => o.timer(t).map({t,i}));

delays$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Will emit

```
[object Object] {
  i: 1,
  t: 100
}
[object Object] {
  i: 0,
  t: 200
}
[object Object] {
  i: 4,
  t: 300
}
[object Object] {
  i: 2,
  t: 1000
}
[object Object] {
  i: 5,
  t: 1100
}
[object Object] {
  i: 3,
  t: 1200
}
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/jurigujege/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: the problem I see is that you don't get the original index, but the emit index. So you don't really recover the original object, but just the delay time. I am editing my question to be more clear on the objective.

Comment: also, the events are not emited on the required timer expiration order, but in the order they are queued.

Comment: forget my last comment, I just discovered that the original method did not fired the events in the order I wanted to. I will have to reconsider my complete strategy.

Comment: "the problem I see is that you don't get the original index" They're the same/original index, but I see what you're getting at. You want them to emit in order of time. Updating my answer.

Comment: yes! that's it! thanks, I could have never figured out, this subtle difference between `.for()` and `.from().flatMap()`

Comment: Yeah... There is a *lot* of API surface. I'm still pretty new to Rx as well and knowing all the API still a hurdle I'm trying to cross. Though, RxJS 5 is trimming the surface down a bit, yay!